# Redirect subdomain requests that do not end with image extension to main domain (htaccess)

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a sub domain that I intend to use for CDN at some point: `images.example.com`. The requests on that subdomain should look like `http://images.example.com/path/to/some/image.jpg`. But currently everything is still hosted on the same server, and the server is configured to have `images.example.com` as alias for `example.com`.

This way both requests will work:
`http://images.example.com/path/to/some/image.jpg`
`http://example.com/path/to/some/image.jpg`

But also other valid request will resolve on both subdomain and tld:
`http://example.com/blog/post/Some-Interesting-Non-Image-Content`
`http://images.example.com/blog/post/Some-Interesting-Non-Image-Content`

Let's assume that if an image is streamed, the URL will have image extension. I want to write a rewrite Cond/Rule for `.htaccess` that will redirect all requests on `images.example.com`, that do not end in image extension `(\.gif|\.png|\.jpeg|\.jpg)` to `example.com`. Also I'd like to have the opposite rule. If a request with `(\.gif|\.png|\.jpeg|\.jpg)` comes to `example.com` - redirect it to `images.example.com`.

I tried several things, they seem to fail (I have trouble working out .htaccess regular expressions):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.example\.com (.*) (?!\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com (.*) (\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://images.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable contains **only** the hostname, as it is transmitted in the HTTP "Host" request header. Therefore, you can't attempt to match things like the request URI in it. You can do that in either the regex pattern in the `RewriteRule` or against the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !\.(jpe?g|gif|ico|png)$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|ico|png)$ http://images.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

The `NC` flag is to indicate the match to be case insensitive.

Comment: This works perfect except in one case - if I have a link like /search?Vehicles%5BMakeID%5D=46 (Vehicles[MakeID]=46), it will brake the link when redirecting from the .htaccess. Whats the reason behind that?

Comment: @Veseliq it shouldn't. Try adding the `NE` flag in the rewrite rule (inside the square brackets).

Comment: Hey - now I saw that while it seems to work for most cases, it seems to fail for some cases like this: http://images.carspending.com/sigimg/975/user/great-wall-hover-h5_big.png I have no idea why, for simpler images like http://images.carspending.com/images/logo.png it works, also if the url does not end in png|jpe?g|gif, it definitely redirects to main domain.

Comment: I will debug later, will remove the rewrite cond for now.

Comment: @Veseliq Your first like `http://images.carspending.com/sigimg/975/user/great-wall-hover-h5_big.png` works for me. I don't get redirected to the main domain when I click on it (or did you already remove the redirect?)

Comment: I had removed the redirect. It's on now for user agent "my-fake-user-agent" (see the edited question). I intend to give some bounty, if someone assists me on this one.

Comment: The problem was the internal redirect of ALL URLs to `index.php` (for routing). I had to add QSA flag for this and it fixed it.